# Как раскодировать BSON в JSON?

Tags: json, delphi

Есть строка в формате BSON (закодированная в base64), как раскодировать ее в JSON-строку?

Строка в таком виде

```
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
```

В [документации](https://scorocode.github.io/scorocode-docs/httpapi/httpapi2/#_5) сказано, что это:

> bson результат запроса, закодированный в base64

Раскодировать base64 пробовал так

```
function Base64Decode(S: string): string;
var
  i, a, b, X: Integer;
begin
  a := 0;
  b := 0;
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    X := pos(S[i], Cod) - 1;
    if X >= 0 then
    begin
      b := b * 64 + X;
      inc(a, 6);
      if a >= 8 then
      begin
        dec(a, 8);
        X := b shr a;
        b := b mod (1 shl a);
        X := X mod 256;
        Result := Result + chr(X);
      end;
    end
    else
      Exit;
  end;
end;
```

После такого раскодировывания получилась строка

```
'â£'#$008A'(¥º)'#$D#$008A'(¢'#$008C#$0084'+î('#$00AD#$008A'(¢»]éä'#$009B'ÓÄz'#$D'Ã(¤ß'#$0098'''ük'#$17'ó'#$0095#6#$008A'M¢'#$008A'(ÖïYÔ'#$0083#$7F'Óº\5'#$0082'\'#$15'»'#$008A'Ù'#$0084#$008E'ÓºX'#$17#$0085'Y'#$1B'½\9»XÒïYÓ'#$0085#$008F'¢'#$0092'~'#$15'ï'#$009A'èÁ'#$0095#$E'Ë'#$0088'%ï'#$0098'5'#$008A')ªß'#$0098'''üh#øj'#6'î(¢'#$008A'+Ó'#$008A#$0092'¢'#$008A'(¤é'#$0092#6#$008A'3¢'#$008A'(×Âj÷Â'#$008E#9'ö'#$7F#1#$A'*÷ý'#$008E#$14'Ì'#$009E#$B'ö'#$008C'¢®(¢'#$008A'_ÓÆYÔ¼rÓºX'#$18#$0082'`ô'#$0084'['#7#$0084'X,'#$0084'^'#4#$0085'a'#$13#$0082'Y'#1#5'_'#$D#$0081'Zü'#$008A'0÷ý'#$008E#$14'Ð'#$009E#$E'öj'#5'í'#$008E#$15'ý(¢'#$0092'~'#$15'ï'#$009A'åë'#$0096'ãî'#$008C'¢'#$008A'(¥¼)'#$C#$008A'(¢'#$008C#$0084'+î('#$00AD#$008A'(¢º'#$0082'â'#1#$0093#$1C'ú'#$0094'5½(ªß'#$0098'''üo'#$17'ö'#$0094'ãí'#$0088'''ý'#$009B'¢'#$008B'*÷ý'#$008E#$14'Ì'#$009E#$B'ö'#$008C'¢®(¢'#$008A'YÒ'#$0083'uÓ¼Xî»xÚ'#$0084#$0082'Ø'#$0083#$009B'Ù½iÛ'#$0080#$008C'ÙºmÛ'#$0083#$0092'ÓºZ'#$D'¼\ç'#$008A'0÷ý'#$008E#$14'Í'#$008A#1'K'#$008D#6#$008A'(¢'#$008D'[¢ô(¢'#$008A'*òs'#$008C'¢'#$0095'(¢'#$008A#$0094#$C'õ'#$0094'Úü'#$008E'âP'#$0097'¢'#$008C'~'#$15'ï'#$009A'äÁ'#$0092#$E'î(Æ'#$008A'(¢»ZÕá`ÕîaÖóYÖÙ^×ÖaÖÏYÔ'#$0081'}Ó»X8'#$0082'Z'#$17#$0081'`ö'#$0084'}¢'#$0092'~'#$15'ï'#$009A'èÁ'#$0095#$E'Ë'#$0088'%ï'#$0098'5'#$008A')ªß'#$0098'''üh#øj'#6'î(¢'#$008A'('
```

Comment: Нашел как конвертировать [Json в Bson](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/BSON). По аналогии можно сделать наоборот.

Comment: @androschuk А есть пример без TJsonObject?
У меня просто есть только строка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это можно сделать вот так:

```
uses
  System.NetEncoding;
...
var
  VBson: string;
  VJson: string;
begin
  VBson := 'ugEAAAMwAGsAAA...
  VJson := Bson2Json(TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(VBson));
  Writeln(VJson);
end;
```

За декодирование BSON отвечает следующий код (взят из [этих сорцов](https://github.com/alefragnani/delphi-james/blob/master/utils/Converters.pas)):

```
uses
  Classes,
  System.JSON,
  System.JSON.BSON,
  System.JSON.Writers,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TJsonStringWriter = class(TJsonTextWriter)
  private
    FStrinBuilder: TStringBuilder;
    FStringWriter: TStringWriter;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function ToString: string;
end;

{ TJsonStringWriter }

constructor TJsonStringWriter.Create;
begin
  FStrinBuilder := TStringBuilder.Create;
  FStringWriter := TStringWriter.Create(FStrinBuilder);
  inherited Create(FStringWriter);
end;

destructor TJsonStringWriter.Destroy;
begin
  FStringWriter.Free;
  FStrinBuilder.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TJsonStringWriter.ToString: string;
begin
  Result := FStrinBuilder.ToString;
end;

function Bson2Json(const ABytes: TBytes): string;
var
  JsonWriter: TJsonStringWriter;
  BsonReader: TBsonReader;
  Stream: TBytesStream;
begin
  Stream := TBytesStream.Create(ABytes);
  BsonReader := TBsonReader.Create(Stream);
  JsonWriter := TJsonStringWriter.Create;
  try
    JsonWriter.WriteToken(BsonReader);
    Result := JsonWriter.ToString;
  finally
    JsonWriter.Free;
    BsonReader.Free;
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев Тогда вызывайте сразу функцию `Bson2Json`. И в вопросе не плохо было бы привести пример вашей строки, чтобы не нужно было угадывать, что у вас и как.

Comment: Добавил, все ссылки привел

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев Обновил ответ, с учётом использования встроенной функции декодирования Base64.

Comment: Спасибо! заработало)