# JavaScript Раскодировать BSON в JSON

Tags: javascript, json, base64

Есть строка в формате BSON (закодированная в base64), как раскодировать ее в JSON-строку?

Строка в таком виде

```
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
```

В [документации](https://scorocode.github.io/scorocode-docs/httpapi/httpapi2/#_5) сказано, что это:

> bson результат запроса, закодированный в base64

Как это раскодировать в JSON?

(Вопрос подобен [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767077/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-bson-%D0%B2-json), но там для Delphi)

Comment: @nick_n_a У меня все равно не такие символы
[Вот что у меня получилось](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12BV147QP7zayTfeJacolzP36m0nX4Rs4)

Comment: Если воспользоваться поисковиком, то получаем опа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541552/is-a-binary-json-javascript-library-available-for-browsers первая ссылка.

Comment: @nick_n_a Да, это я тоже нашел, но там у меня ругается на exports из bson.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил

Код [этого](https://mcraiha.github.io/tools/BSONhexToJSON/bson.js) файла + эта функция:

```
function myFunction(str) {
    var BSON = bson().BSON;
    var rawBytes = window.atob(str);
    var uintArray = new Uint8Array(rawBytes.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rawBytes.length; i++)
    {
        uintArray[i] = rawBytes.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var doc_2 = BSON.deserialize(uintArray);
    return JSON.stringify(doc_2, null, 4);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

есть функции для работы с бейс 64.

[WindowBase64](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64)

а после уже и превращай джейсон в объект и работай.

Comment: А вот как из bson в json конвертировать?

Comment: Например, `atob("ugEAA...");` выдает строку типа такой `"º (нечитаемый символ) _id...(нечитаемый символ) hdhYjsYg...."`, в которой уже видны параметры нужного мне объекта, но это же не JSON, как переконыертировать в него?

Comment: Можно на https://www.base64decode.org/ зайти, и подтвердить, что у вас полно нечитаемых символов. это означает одно из двух - либо ваш запрос битый, либо BSON нельзя расшифровать через base64-decode напрямую, а ваш источник этой информации github - не может быть достоверным. Или как последний вариант - запрос зашифрован нестандартной кодировкой.

Comment: @nick_n_a Однако, в вопросе для Delphi, который я указал ([этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767077/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-bson-%D0%B2-json)) все декодируется нормально. Ведь мы не сразу получаем JSON после декодирования, я так понимаю, что это все еще BSON

Comment: То что Delphi разкодировал - не является показателем. За вас программу на Delphi переводить на js никто не будет. Откуда взята строчка? Может у вас "кодировщик" не в той кодировке кодирует? Или не правильно настроен?

Comment: @nick_n_a Строчка - это полученный ответ при запросе, который я указал в документации, не я ее составлял

Comment: BSON не может быть перекодирован в JSON напрямую, потому что открываем спецификацию http://bsonspec.org/spec.html читаем. Соответственно становится понятно что за странные символы после base64 декодирования. Т.е. раскодировать BASE64 - это только первый шаг. А дельше нужно или поискать либу или самому писать.

Comment: @nick_n_a У меня все равно не такие символы [Вот что у меня получилось](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12BV147QP7zayTfeJacolzP36m0nX4Rs4)